# Active Directory Remote (VPN) Users are facing problem with newly set group policies

Tags: windows, active-directory, vpn, group-policy, gpo

I am facing some issue with Active directory group policies,

The issue is i have many users working from home and all of them are using one SSL to connect to the company domain their file sharing is working fine, their group old group policy updating but i have setup few new group policy and they are not reflecting on remote users system,

For example there is one policy i have setup for deploying an application using GPO to remote users so when they restart the system the policy get applied to them and the MSi package should install to their system,

I tried GPUPDATE /force, /synch, normal mode and admin mode nothing helped

I am not sure why this is happening and how to fix that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to software development while you question appears to be related to sysadmin's tasks and therefore is off-topic here. There are guys here who could help you for sure but I doubt anyone will even try because your question will get deleted anyway soon. You will have better chances for the answer either at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServelFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal cause software deployment via GPO is installed before user login, and your VPN connection is established after user login, non of computer installation GPO will work via VPN, there is other option to deploy software on VPN connection, Fog Project it's open source software deployment.